# Extract specific data output from beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using this script. It provides the data that I am wanting however all I need is the "Updated date" part. Trying to get rid of the text that follows after.

```
# import library
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

# Request to website and download HTML contents
url='https://data.ed.gov/dataset/college-scorecard-all-data-files-through-6-2020/resources'
req=requests.get(url)
content=req.text
soup=BeautifulSoup(content)
raw=soup.findAll(class_="module-content")[3].text
print(raw.strip())
```

This is the output I get:

```
Updated 1-19-2021
      
      
        
          
          

        
          
            

There are no views created for this resource yet.
```

The bold and italicized output is what I am trying to get and not the other item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`find_next()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all-next-and-find-next) method which returns the *first* next match:

```
raw=soup.findAll(class_="module-content")[3].find_next(text=True)
```

Full example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

# Request to website and download HTML contents
url='https://data.ed.gov/dataset/college-scorecard-all-data-files-through-6-2020/resources'
req=requests.get(url)
content=req.text
soup=BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
raw=soup.findAll(class_="module-content")[3].find_next(text=True)
print(raw.strip())
```

Output:

```
Updated 1-19-2021
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://data.ed.gov/dataset/college-scorecard-all-data-files-through-6-2020/resources"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

print(soup.select_one(".inner-primary .module-content").contents[0].strip())
```

Prints:

```
Updated 1-19-2021
```